# Vector Analysis in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: calculus, manifolds, vector-analysis

I'm asked to do this computation from a differential manifolds text: $${d\alpha}=\left(\frac{\partial \:R}{\partial \:y}-\frac{\partial \:Q}{\partial \:z}\right)\left(dy\wedge \:dz\right)+\left(\frac{\partial \:P}{\partial \:z}-\frac{\partial \:R}{\partial \:z}\right)\left(dz\wedge \:dx\right)+\left(\frac{\partial \:Q}{\partial \:x}-\frac{\partial \:P}{\partial \:y}\right)\left(dx\wedge \:dy\right)$$
I've waded through a Calc 1-2 answers-provided book, and started a differential equations book, but I'm really not good at all at calculations of calculus.  Any help?

It comes from the chapter on "Tensor Fields: local theory" under the section "exterior derivative" in a subsection concerning grad, curl, div.  Also, the differential equations textbook it too advanced for me to understand anything except the first chapter. I'm sort of looking at solving math backwards from harder problems to put in place the basics.  It just how my mind works, and it keeps me interested, and interesting.

The one-form $\alpha = Pdx + Qdy + Rdz$ which is analogous to vector field $F = Pi + Qj + Rk$ where $i, j, k$ are $\frac\partial{\partial \:x}, \frac\partial{\partial \:y}, \frac\partial{\partial \:z}$. I hope this makes it more clear.  Thanks.

Also, $$curl F= \left(\frac{\partial \:R}{\partial \:y}-\frac{\partial \:Q}{\partial \:z}\right)i+\left(\frac{\partial \:P}{\partial \:z}-\frac{\partial \:R}{\partial \:z}\right)j+\left(\frac{\partial \:Q}{\partial \:x}-\frac{\partial \:P}{\partial \:y}\right)k$$
I'm starting to see that the computation would entail the relation between the two large equations here.

Rather, thanks Duncan Rampage for pointing me to the beginning of the subsection on Exterior Derivative.  I feel the very definition of it gives the basis for the computing required in the question.  I had read the chapter a week ago without much connection to it.  Feel stupid now for asking, but thank you.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some context. For example, how are $\alpha$, $P$, $Q$, and $R$ defined? What part of the differential manifolds text does this appear in, i.e. is this about practicing basics of differential forms, understanding the relation between exterior derivative and div/curl/grad in Euclidean spaces, or something about Riemannian manifolds? Also what are your own experiences? Are you reading the differential textbook because you need to know some results from it, or going through it cover to cover as in a course?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the exterior derivative?

Comment: Yes, this should be $d\alpha$, not $\partial\alpha$, where $d$ is the exterior derivative. This formula follows immediately from the definition of $d$ and the fact that $dy\wedge dx = -dx\wedge dy$. Perhaps some of my YouTube lectures on differential forms and applications will help. See the link in my profile.